# Alto LX erratic start up behavior

Tags: fuel-system

I have been facing a start up problem with my Maruti 800 LX recently. I have changed the distributor, spark plugs and also replaced the battery. Any recommendations?

Comment: Can you describe the start up problem? Is the engine turning over? Does the problem occur all the time?

Comment: Takes a long time to start, it cranks fine but sometimes takes unusually long to fire the engine. At other times, it starts fine, no multiple attempts whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For intermittent long cranks, I'd check the following:

- **spark plug cables:** inspect them for cracks in the insulation and test their resistance with a multimeter, make sure they are within specification
- **injectors:** test their resistance with a multimeter, make sure they are within specification
- **fuel filter:** if it's too old, replace it
- **air filter:** if it's too dirty, replace it
- **fuel pump:** there isn't an easy way to test it, does it humm every time you turn the key to "on" (without trying to start)? If it doesn't inspect the electrical connection to it, and be ready to replace the pump
- **fuel pressure:** measure it, make sure it's within spec. If it isn't, it could be the fuel pressure regulator, or even the fuel pump itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful. The plug cables were changed when i got the new spark plugs last week, air filter is new as well, changed in oct. The fuel filter, fuel pump and pressure will need a qualified help, will take it to the garage this afternoon. Thanks again.